# jquery load function get only div

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, modal-dialog

I am new to jquery and would like to add a vertical scrollbar to this jquery modal window if the text within the modal window is large. Where in the code should I add it and how can I add it.

The code is below:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.dialog-ajax').click(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $this = $(this);
       var URL     = $(this).attr('href');
       var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialog');
       var dialogOptions = {
                             height: 448,
                             width: 736,
                             modal: true,

                             close: function(event, ui){
                               $('#dialog').empty(); 
                             }
                           };

    if(dialogbox==null) {
      $this.after("<div id=\"dialog\"></div>");

    }

    jQuery('#dialog').load(URL + " #content").dialog(dialogOptions);


    });

});
```

Thanks much appreciated
Cheers

Comment: You can just do that with CSS. Set a fixed height and set `overflow-y:auto;`

Answer (score -1):

I would do that with css. This should do it.

```
#dialog {overflow: scroll}
```

Comment: That is always giving a scrollbar horizontal and vertical.